# Kubuntu installation asks to install on entire partition

Tags: installation, partitioning, kubuntu

I'm trying to install Kubuntu 12.10 on my computer, but when i get to the part where we chose the partition to install Kubuntu, I only have three options and all of them includes using the 100% of my HDD. Since I did't want to have any problems with my other partitions, I canceled the installation. Here's the picture of the screen i mentioned[image: installation screen]

I'm actually not sure about what it's going to do because I don't have enough knowledge of technical English even though I'm an ELT student. The second bar on the image really bugged me and I thought i better seek for help. Any kind of help would be appreciated by the way. Thank you for your help in advance and have a nice day.

Answer (score 5):

This was solved with information given in comments.

[mikewhatever said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250807/kubuntu-installation-asks-to-install-on-entire-partition#comment312805_250807):

> .... The problem seems to be that the hdd already has 4 primary
>   partitions. If that is the case, you won't be able to create more,
>   before deleting one. Your current options are: delete one of the
>   partitions and then create partitions manually, use the Windows
>   installer, use VirtualBox. PS: What's ELT.

[Seth added](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250807/kubuntu-installation-asks-to-install-on-entire-partition#comment312809_250807):

> Yes, according to the picture you already four primary partitions:
>   `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`, `/dev/sda5` and `/dev/sda6`. I hard drive
>   can only have four primary partitions at a time.

The OP [reported](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250807/kubuntu-installation-asks-to-install-on-entire-partition#comment312823_250807) that this worked.